# Python rfft does not yield correct phase information

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing, fft

So I'm trying to write a code to implement the Forman Phase Correction to correct phase-related asymmetries in an interferogram.  The premise of the routine is to convolute the fourier transform of exp(-i*PhaseAngle) with your interferogram.  This technique has been around since the 60s, and it should work, but I've been having difficulties.

As such, I used python to generate an interferogram with exactly 0 phase angle to debug my code.  Once I got that working, I generated an interferogram with 0.3 radians of phase, and my phase array does not look like a constant 0.3, and I'm not sure whats happening.  I've tried numpy arctan, numpy arctan2, and numpy angle all to bad results.  I've also tried apodizing my data and that didn't help, so I removed that for clarity.

Any ideas why I'm not getting the correct phase information from my program?  If you plug this code into python you get some wonky phase graph.

I'm fairly confident in my processing functions, and the true meat of the code is below those, where I call those functions to process my interferogram.  The basic routine to calculate the phase angle is:

-Truncate the interferogram to some small number of points (I used 401)
-Rotate it so that the zero path difference (ZPD) is the first data point
-Multiply the ZPD value by 0.5 (not sure the reason for this, but academic papers say that you have to do this)
-Take the real (one sided) fft of the resulting data
-Take the arc tangent of the imaginary divided by the real to get the phase angle

So I'm following the above routine for an artificially generated interferogram with 0.3 radians of phase shift, but have been unable to reproduce that phase error with the routine.  Any ideas?  Thanks for any help you all can offer!

EDIT:  A lot of what this question boils down to is how should I arrange my signal(that has a known, constant, phase error of 0.3) before applying the fft such that the imaginary part of my result is a constant 0.3?  And further, what type of fft in python should I use to achieve this result? I'm highly confident that I'm successfully generating a signal with a constant phase error of 0.3.

Code:

```
## Importer
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
from scipy.fftpack import dct,idct,dst,idst
import cmath
from scipy import signal
from scipy.integrate import simps
import csv

## Generate interferogram
xlist = np.arange(-0.03, 0.03,(1/15798.69))
numPhase = 200
print 'generating interferogram...'
def infGen(nu, xval):
    h = 6.626*10**-34 #J*s
    c = 3*10**8 #m/s
    kB = 1.38*10**-23 #J/K
    T = 300.0 # K    
    return 0.5*2*h*c*c*nu*nu*nu*(100.0**3)*1/(np.exp(h*c*nu*100/(kB*T))-1)*np.cos(2*np.pi*nu*xval+0.3)
interferogram = list()
intError = list()
for i in range(len(xlist)):
    xval = xlist[i]
    value, error = scipy.integrate.quad(infGen,500,4000,args = (xval),limit=150)
    interferogram.append(value)
    intError.append(error)

## Processing functions
def truncate(interferogram, centerburst):
    truncated=list()
    truncatedLength=2*numPhase+1
    for i in range(truncatedLength):
        truncated.append(interferogram[centerburst-(truncatedLength/2)+i])
    #Compute interferogram averages to normalize
    truncavg=np.average(truncated)
    #Normalize the interferograms by their averages
    for i in range(len(truncated)):
        truncated[i]=truncated[i]-truncavg
    return truncated
def rotateMertz(interferogram):
    rotated=list()
    for i in range(len(interferogram)-numPhase):
        rotated.append(interferogram[i+numPhase])
    for i in range(numPhase):
        rotated.append(interferogram[i])
    return rotated   
def getphaseangle(fftdata):
    phaseangle=list()
    for i in range(len(fftdata)):
        #phaseangle.append(np.angle(fftdata[i]))
        """if fftdata[i].imag < 0:
            phaseangle[i] = phaseangle[i]+2*np.pi
        if fftdata[i].real>0 and np.abs(fftdata[i].imag)<(10**-10) and fftdata[i].imag<0:
            phaseangle[i] = 0"""
        phaseangle.append(np.arctan(fftdata[i].imag/fftdata[i].real))
    return phaseangle
def findZPD(inf):
    # finds the index of the zpd for a given interferogram
    maxVal=max(np.abs(inf))
    x = [i for i, j in enumerate(inf) if j==maxVal]
    return x[0]

## Process Interferogram
inf = interferogram
phasedataTrunc = truncate(inf, findZPD(inf))
phasedataRot = rotateMertz(phasedataTrunc) # Rotates so ZPD is first value
phasedataRot[0] = phasedataRot[0]*0.5 # Multiply ZPD value by 0.5
phasedataFFT = np.fft.rfft(phasedataRot)
plt.figure('real part')
plt.plot(phasedataFFT.real)
plt.figure('imaginary part')
plt.plot(phasedataFFT.imag)
plt.figure('imaginary/real')
plt.plot(phasedataFFT.imag/phasedataFFT.real)
phaseAngle = getphaseangle(phasedataFFT)
plt.figure('phase angle')
plt.plot(phaseAngle)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Is the interferogram real or complex?

Comment: The interferogram is real, as in it normally is a physical measurement.  You can take the "real" fft as python describes it, because I'm only interested in the positive frequency information in the fft domain.  My understanding is that the only difference between numpys fft and rfft is that the fft gives you both the negative and positive frequency information, while the rfft only gives the positive half.  What is your concern about the real/complexity of the interferogram?

Comment: What do you expect as output? A constant phase at 0.3?

Comment: Yep! I've defined my interferogram to be shifted by a phase of 0.3 in the line where I include the +0.3 in the cosine definition of the interferogram.

Comment: Something else that I just discovered is that the fft is dropping data points. For example, if I take a 201 point list, and take the rfft of it, I get a 101 point array.  Then, if I take the irfft of it, I get an array with 200 points, 1 less.  Shouldn't the irfft(rfft(x)) return x, not x minus 1 data point?

Comment: In the return function of infGen, might there be some potential ambiguities / missing parenthesis? I also don't get including 0.5*2. Not clear on how that function is supposed to return a constant phase of 0.3, given the inputs.

Comment: So the interferogram is generated by multiplying the curve for a black body with 0.5*cos(2*pi*wavenumber*position+phase).  The 0.5 * 2 is that theres a 2 in the black body equation and a 0.5 from the interferogram definition.  I had written the functions separately initially to verify that they were correct and the copied and pasted them together with a multiplication sign to insure that there weren't any ambiguities, but that left redundant numbers.

Comment: I'm highly confident that the generator function is working correctly.  I think the error is somewhere in the fft or phase angle generator part of the code, but I'm not sure.